# HTTP 400 (E9999) received when creating jar package using packages API

Tags: here-olp

I receive an error
`{"status":400,"code":"E9999","message":"HTTP 400 Bad Request","messageTemplate":"{unknown.error}","templateOptions":null,"errors":[]}` when creating a ~50mb jar package on OLP using the packages api

The error code is not listed here 
https://developer.here.com/olp/documentation/pipeline/api-reference-swagger.html#operation/createPackage
And appears to be a placeholder for an unknown issue.

Comment: It says bad request, and the documentation points, you will get `400` if the required fields were not provided.

Comment: I understand the 400, but the code and message are unhelpful. There is a single parameter to include to the ReST API which is the jar as a File, I don't understand how I haven't provided the correct fields when the request seems so simple

Comment: please create a support ticket with pipeline details and we will have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the following in your request:
* Content-Type = application/octet-stream
* request body is multi-part
* executionTimeout may need to be increased